# Safari/IOS Safari service worker skip waiting doesn't work

Tags: javascript, safari, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, browser-cache

I have a Django app that implements progressive web app functionality. To do so I needed to include a service worker and that is where all my issues are. My app needs to be able to reload the main page frequently (Every minute or so at least) since the display will change values on the page. Ideally, I would like the user to be able to simply refresh the page or changes get pushed to the client page.

The problem I am having (at least from what I understand) is that the updated service worker is waiting to install until the outdated service worker dies (i.e. when the page closes.) So to fix this, I read that you can have the service worker skip waiting and install right away.

This seems to work okay in chrome, but in Safari and IOS Safari it does not. I am not sure if I am over looking something here, or maybe there is an alternative to get this to work on all browsers.

ServiceWorker.js

```
var staticCacheName = "django-pwa-v" + new Date().getTime();

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {

  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(staticCacheName).then(function(cache) {
      return cache.addAll([
        '/'
      ]);
    }).then(function() {
      return self.skipWaiting();
    })
  );
});

// Clear cache on activate
self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
            return Promise.all(
                cacheNames
                    .filter(cacheName => (cacheName.startsWith("django-pwa-")))
                    .filter(cacheName => (cacheName !== staticCacheName))
                    .map(cacheName => caches.delete(cacheName))
            );
        })
    );
    return self.clients.claim();
});

addEventListener('message', messageEvent => {
  if (messageEvent.data === 'skipWaiting') return skipWaiting();
});

addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith((async () => {
    if (event.request.mode === "navigate" &&
      event.request.method === "GET" &&
      registration.waiting &&
      (await clients.matchAll()).length < 2
    ) {
      registration.waiting.postMessage('skipWaiting');
      return new Response("", {headers: {"Refresh": "0"}});
    }
    return await caches.match(event.request) ||
      fetch(event.request);
  })());
});
```

Comment: I do not know much JavaScript but check out pwabuilder.com and that should generate a Service Worker for you based on your needs

Comment: Dude... This is exactly what I needed!! It worked perfectly.@ShadowDev

Comment: Glad to help man :)